# Working SoundCloud example project for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, audio, soundcloud

Does anyone know of one that is easy to get started? I would like to post audio files from my app to Facebook via Soundcloud, but the API is not super accessible for a novice like myself.

Comment: Um.. you can't just vote down with no reason :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper) is as good as it gets for now.